# Convert string to date in a specific format without time

Tags: java, android

I have a doubt that when I am converting a String to date then It will return it as:

**Sun Apr 30 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2017**

but I want the format to be as:

**2017-04-30**

```
Date last_date_date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2017-04-30");
```

So Which method I need to apply for that?

Comment: Are you trying to print last_date_date directly.

Comment: No If I want to check then I convert it in string format and chck it, but I want it to be in Date datatype only and in the format a "2017-04-30", I want to show time with it

Comment: In reference to your message: "Log.i("Date",""+last_date_date);"
java.util.Date has a toString() format : dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy. 
It takes default time as 00:00:00 even if you don't provide one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working well, here is a proof:

```
Date last_date_date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2017-04-30");
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(last_date_date));
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
2017-04-30
```

Comment: Log.i("Date",""+last_date_date); in android

Comment: Use `Log.i("Date", new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(last_date_date));`

Answer (score 0):

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

//current date into your required format
String str = dateFormat.format(new Date());
```

Comment: but wasn't this `Sun Apr 30 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2017` already in Date format?

Answer (score 0):

```
DateFormat df = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date lastDateDate = df.parse("2017-04-30");


String date = df.format(lastDateDate);
```